# Login to site with captcha php

Tags: php, authentication, captcha

I want to login in `http://bo500.s.traaviaan.ir/` ( or another servers ) with php, but I have a problem with Captcha code .
I don't know how to get the Captcha image and show it in a form?

As well I used this code :

```
<?
if ( !empty($_POST['user'])){
    $user = $_POST['user'];
}
if ( !empty($_POST['pwtraa'])){
    $pw = $_POST['pwtraa'];
}
if ( !empty($_POST['captcha'])){
    $capt = $_POST['captcha'];
}
$login_url = 'http://bo500.s.traaviaan.ir/login.php';
$post_data = "user=".$user."&pwtraa=".$pw."&captcha=".$capt;
$ch = curl_init();
$agent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $login_url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
$postResult = curl_exec($ch);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Please help , Sorry for bad English

Answer (score 0):

In the login form on that page there is this input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="login" value="1428775885">
```

And the captchas are here:

```
http://bo500.s.traaviaan.ir/code.php?174865
```

The number from the "login" value will be associated with a captcha code in the backend on that site.

Have your PHP script access that login page before someone logs in and get the captcha image link and save the login form input id.

Then serve your user the login form, the captcha and have him enter the code.

Then, when you login to the other site, make sure to include both the login value and the captcha solution in your postdata.

Answer (score -1):

```
`$im = ImageCreate(200,50); // creation du cadre du captcha 
            $dossier = 'images_captcha'; // dossier de rangement 
             if(!is_dir($dossier)){//verification de l'existance  du dossier de rangement 
                mkdir($dossier);  //creation du dossier de rangement si celui ci n'existe pas
             }
            $lettres = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');// lettre et carractère du tri

            $alea = mt_rand(4,8);// selection aleatoire du nombre de carractère du texte captcha 
            $recp=NULL;
            $result = NULL;
            $string = NULL;
            $str = NULL;
    for($i=0; $i<$alea; $i++){ // boucle de formation des mots deux mot du captcha
            $result= $alea/2;// division du nombre de carractere du grand mot par 2
            $recp = array_rand($lettres); //tri pour recuperation d'un emplacement précis dans le tableau de lettre alphanumerique
            $recp = $lettres[$recp];//recuperation de la lettre en fonction de son emplecement recupérer précedement 

            if($result >= $i){ // recuperation et creation du deuxieme mot
                $string .= $recp;
            }else{
                $str .= $recp; 
            }
    }
            $string = $string." ".$str;//concatenation des deux mots créés 
            $gris[1] = ImageColorAllocate ($im, 110, 110, 110);//couleurs gris 
            $gris[9] = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 128, 0);//couleurs gris
            $gris[8] = ImageColorAllocate ($im, 0, 0, 0); //couleurs noir
            $gris[0] = ImageColorAllocate ($im, 255, 255, 255); //couleurs blanc     
            $gris[2] = ImageColorAllocate ($im, 130, 130, 130); //couleurs gris
            $gris[3] = ImageColorAllocate ($im, 150, 150, 150);//couleurs gris 
            $gris[4] = ImageColorAllocate ($im, 170, 170, 170); //couleurs gris
            $gris[5] = ImageColorAllocate ($im, 190, 190, 190); //couleurs gris
            $gris[6] = ImageColorAllocate ($im, 210, 210, 210); //couleurs gris
            $gris[7] = ImageColorAllocate ($im, 230, 230, 230);//couleurs gris

            $px     = mt_rand(20,100); // detection de la position x de l'ecriture sur l'image
        if($px == 0 || $px == ""){
                $px = 50;
        }else{
                $px = $px;
        }
            $width = mt_rand(1,30);// detection de la position Y de l'ecriture sur l'image
        if($width == 0 || $width == ""){
                $width = 30;
        }else{
                $width = $width;
        }
        $rand = mt_rand(111111111,999999999).time();//creation du nom de l'image créée
            imagestring($im, 5, $px, $width, $string, $gris[7]);// ecriture sur l'image 
            imagestring($im, 5, $px, $width + 2, $string, $gris[7]);//doublé l'ecriture pour  rendre l'ecriture flou
            imagecolortransparent($im, $gris[1]);//rendre  le background transparent
            imagepng($im,"$dossier/$rand.png");//creation du bloc d'ecriture et enregistrement sous forme d'image
            $image_gerer = array_rand(array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7'));//selection aleatoire d'image
        if($image_gerer == 0){
            $image_gerer = 1;
        }
            $source = imagecreatefrompng("$dossier/$rand.png"); //recuperation de l'image source precedement enregistré
            $destination = imagecreatefrompng("$dossier/img_system/".$image_gerer.".png"); //recuperation de la photo a mettre en arriere plan 
            $posi = array_rand(array('20','30','40','50','-40','-50','60','-60','10'));// determination aleatoire de la rotation de l'image source sur l'image de fond
            $source = imagerotate($source, $posi, 1, 0);//rotation 
            $largeur_source = imagesx($source);// comme le dit le nom de la variable  : detection de la largeur de l'image source
            $hauteur_source = imagesy($source);// hauteur de la source 
            $largeur_destination = imagesx($destination);//largeur de l'image de background
            $hauteur_destination = imagesy($destination);//hauteur de l'image de background
            $destination_x = ($largeur_destination/2) - ($largeur_source/2);// emplacement de l'image source sur l'axe x 
            $destination_y =  ($hauteur_destination/2) - ($hauteur_source/2);// emplacement de l'image source sur l'axe Y
            imagecopymerge($destination, $source, $destination_x, $destination_y, 0, 0, $largeur_source, $hauteur_source, 40);//fusion des deux image pour la formation final du captcha 
            imagepng($destination,"$dossier/$rand.png");//enregistrement du captcha
            //imagejpeg($destination);
            $captch['lien'] = "$dossier/$rand.png"; 
            $captch['code'] = $string;
            //destruction des image dans la memoire 
            imagedestroy($im);
            imagedestroy($destination);
            //retour des information 
            echo $captch;`
```

Comment: You should format this code correctly and actually explain it and what the problem was in the original code posted.